# Faster way to loop through large transaction lists

Tags: excel, vba

**Objective:** I am building the a macro below with the intention comparing what has changed in a transaction list (TL) as it grows with ongoing posting of new transactions. I want to know exactly what has changed between the new TL and the old TL, so that Old TL + Changes = New TL...

**How I did it so far:** The method is to flag transactions in 2 separate sheets (old TL, new TL) with same columns layout filled with transactions as follows:

- Exact match (exact same string of concatenated row in both sheets)
- Partial match (not exact same string, but same document number in both sheets)
- No match (no exact string, no exact doc number in other sheet)

**Challenge:** My code runs but with 50,000 records between the sheets it takes about 15 minutes

**Question:** Does anyone have a suggestion how I could make the code below run faster (extract) - where all variables are ranges except nrws and cls which is are doubles.

```
    For l = 2 To nrws
        Set nkey = nTL.Cells(l, cls + 1)
        Set ndoc = nTL.Cells(l, 5)
        nTL.Cells(l, cls + 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(nkeyList, nkey)
        nTL.Cells(l, cls + 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(okeyList, nkey)
        nTL.Cells(l, cls + 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ndocList, ndoc)
        nTL.Cells(l, cls + 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(odocList, ndoc)
        If nTL.Cells(l, cls + 3) = 0 Then
            If nTL.Cells(l, cls + 5) = 0 Then
                nTL.Cells(l, cls + 6) = "No Match"
            Else: nTL.Cells(l, cls + 6) = "Partial Match"
            End If
        ElseIf nTL.Cells(l, cls + 2) = nTL.Cells(l, cls + 3) And nTL.Cells(l, cls + 4) = nTL.Cells(l, cls + 5) Then
            nTL.Cells(l, cls + 6) = "Exact Match"
        ElseIf nTL.Cells(l, cls + 2) = nTL.Cells(l, cls + 3) Then
            nTL.Cells(l, cls + 6) = "Partial Match"
        Else
            nTL.Cells(l, cls + 6) = "Check"
        End If
    Next l
```

Thanks in advance - Let me know if I omitted something.

Comment: For that amount of data my first suggestion would be: Use anything but VBA! • If it has to be VBA read everything into an array, perform everything over that array and then write it back into cells. This way Excel only has to handle with simple data values but not with cell objects that come with a lot more overhead than just the values.

Comment: And use application.match then check if error to see if it exists. Countif is slow.

Comment: Expanding on the array idea, VBA makes it very easy to take values off of the sheet and write arrays back onto the sheet. Its as simple as `MyArray = MyTableRange.Value` to create a 2D array of all the values, and then `MyTableRange.Value = MyArray` to fill the range with each value from the array (make sure they're the same size).

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback! I thought of the array, but I understood from somewhere that there is limit to the number of items that can be stored in an array. So MyArray... could hold 25000-50000 elements? I will give it a try for sure at least for some variables.

Comment: @yamou you can read only the columns and rows you need into an array. Also if that is too much still then you can eg make one array with column 1 to 3 and another with column 6 to 8 (same amount of rows) this way you can spare out the columns 4 and 5 for example. Just keep the splitting as low as possible.

Comment: Just curious, what is the range of nkeyList, okeyList, ndocList and odocList ? is it a column or a row or a range across row and column? It seems you are comparing a number not a string ? (Please CMIIW). If you have sample image of sheet oldTL and newTL maybe it's better.

Comment: btw, I test your code but without the writing of the `countif`. So, the sample data I make, the new key, old key, new doc and old doc are already has number value in it for 60000 rows. For example, row2 : blank, 0, blank, 0 (if cls+3 = 0 and cls+5 = 0). Row3 : blank, 0, blank, 2  (if cls+3 = 0 and cls+5 <> 0). Row4 : 7,7,7,7 (if cls+2 = cls+3 = cls+4 = cls+5). Row5 : 9,9,4,7 (if cls+2 = cls+3). The code runs in not more than 5 seconds. So maybe you can check if the writing of the `CountIf` for 50000 rows (remove all the IF code) which takes so long.

Comment: @karma: they are columns with strings (keys - concatenated row cells and docs - alphanumeric document numbers)

Comment: @yamou, thanks for the answer. I wonder what is the value of `nTL.Cells(l, cls + 2)` after the code pass this line `nTL.Cells(l, cls + 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(nkeyList, nkey)` ? Is it a number or a text/string ?

Comment: Thanks for your continued feedback. Column cls + 2..5 they are all numbers which are results of the various counts of matches in old and new TL (count concat key in old TL, Count of concat key in new TL of key, Count of doc num in old TL, and Count of doc num in new TL). The last cls + 6 is the result (match type)